# Redirect to a different domain with Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious, template-toolkit

at Route / of my page, the user can see a button:

```
<a href="[% h.url_for('post_route', param => someValue) %]" target="_blank"><button>click me</button></a>
```

A click on this button will open a new tab and do a post to the "post_route".
in the controller sub of the post_route, i want to check some things and then redirect the user to a different domain, let's just say for example to www.redirecturl.com.
I also need to send payload to www.redirecturl.com (post request).
the domain www.redirecturl.com will then check the value i sent to it and render a specific page.

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.
If i use i.e. `$self->redirect_to('www.redirecturl.com');`
i get a "redirect error" in my browser with the information "This problem can sometimes occur when cookies are disabled or denied.".

So... any idea how i can redirect with Mojolicious to a completely different domain and send some payload in the body?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `www.redirecturl.com` is a valid URL, but it doesn't refer to another host. If you redirect to `www.redirecturl.com` from `http://x.y.com/foo/index.html`, then you are redirecting to `http://x.y.com/foo/www.redirecturl.com`. Provide the correct URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `redirect_to()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::DefaultHelpers#redirect_to) gives the following examples:

```
$c = $c->redirect_to('named', foo => 'bar');
$c = $c->redirect_to('named', {foo => 'bar'});
$c = $c->redirect_to('/index.html');
$c = $c->redirect_to('http://example.com/index.html');
```

From which, we can guess that if you want to redirect to a different domain, then you need to give it a complete URI - not just a domain name.